# How do I install the 'collectd' Redis plugin on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: redis, collectd

How do I install the 'collectd' [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29) plugin on [Amazon Linux 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image#Amazon_Linux_AMI)?

When I run `yum list | grep collectd`, I do not see Redis. How do I install the Redis plugin for 'collectd'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redis plugin for collectd may not be available in the default repositories. You can try adding the EPEL repository and then installing the plugin using the following steps:

1. Install the EPEL repository:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
```

2. Install collectd and the redis plugin:

```
sudo yum install collectd collectd-redis
```

3. Configure the redis plugin by editing the collectd configuration file:

```
sudo vi /etc/collectd.conf
```

Add the following lines to the file:

```
LoadPlugin redis
<Plugin redis>
  <Node "mynode">
    Host "localhost"
    Port "6379"
    Redis_version 5
    Redis_key "myrediskey"
    Redis_field "myredisfield"
  </Node>
</Plugin>
```

4. Restart the collectd service:

```
sudo systemctl restart collectd
```

Note: Make sure that redis is already installed and running on your system before attempting to install and configure the collectd plugin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to install Collectd. To do so, enter the following command:

```
sudo yum install collectd
```

After that, you need to install Redis:

```
sudo yum install redis
```

Install the Redis plugin for Collectd:

```
sudo yum install collectd-redis
```

Edit the Collectd configuration file */etc/collectd.conf* and add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
LoadPlugin redis

<Plugin redis>
  <Node "redis">
    Host "localhost"
    Port "6379"
  </Node>
</Plugin>
```

This will configure Collectd to monitor the Redis instance running on the local host.

And all you have to do now is restart the Collectd service to apply the changes you made to the configuration file using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart collectd
```

That covers it.